# To the castle you go

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

You arrive at the Bridge of Death, one known for its difficult questions. The keeper arises and speaks: "Who would cross the Bridge of Death must answer me these questions three! There the other side, ye see."

You are asked:

> 1: What is your name?
>   2: What is your quest?
>   3: What is your favorite color?

Hint:

> You are the first visitor to the bridge in a party of five.

Bonus Questions:
What is the name of the troll?
How many in your party die at the bridge?

Comment: This is not a _puzzle_.

Comment: I agree with Gareth here, it's essentially just a trivia question.

Comment: Ok. I'll remove it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it

1: What is your name?

> My name is 'Sir Lancelot of Camelot'.

2: What is your quest?

> To seek the Holy Grail.

3: What is your favorite color?

> blue

From

> Monty Python's Holy Grail

Bonus
What is the name of the troll?

> The Bridgekeeper or the old man from scene twenty-four

How many in your party die at the bridge?

> Two (Robin and Galahad)